# Error for Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, datepicker

I am using the following code; the calendar icon does not appear, and there is an error logged to the console: 404 not found.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY'
            });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker10'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your font files are missing. Please create folder named fonts and include font files to it. It will work.

eg: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2